# Using Android Studio and AVD Emulator on virtual machines by remote desktop

Tags: android, virtual-machine, emulation

I don't speak english very well.

I'll try a say:
On our school server, we've installed Windows Server Multipoint 2012 and our network manager's created a virtual machine shared by teacher and the students. 
I (teacher) have installed Android Studio 3.0 from my account. Without any problems, we all can execute Android Studio e develop our personal app.

In order to debug apps we wanted to use AVD emulation. The problem is that the first instance of the emulator is common to every student, so we can't run our personal emulator.

There is a way to set used TCP port of the emulator o launch Android Studio on each account setted to listen to emulator on several an unique port numbers?

Or another solution?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Solved from command line.

emulator @EmulatorName -port xxxx

where xxx is a unique port number.

adb -s emulator-xxx install -r path to app's name